# Как правильно использовать функцию validateAuthKey() в yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Я провёл исследования **стандартного примера**, и выяснил, что функция `validateAuthKey()` вообще не вызывается. Для чего она тогда нужна, **как её правильно вызвать, как правильно с ней работать?**

```
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        Yii::info('test ================');
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validateAuthKey()` проверяет `$authKey` - хэш, который хранится в куках. Вызывается для авторизации с помощью cookie в `yii\web\User::loginByCookie` при `$enableAutoLogin = true`

```
    protected function loginByCookie()
        {
            ...
            if ($identity->validateAuthKey($authKey)) {
                if ($this->beforeLogin($identity, true, $duration)) {
                    $this->switchIdentity($identity, $this->autoRenewCookie ? $duration : 0);
                    $ip = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP();
                    Yii::info("User '$id' logged in from $ip via cookie.", __METHOD__);
                    $this->afterLogin($identity, true, $duration);
                }
            }
            ... 
        }
```

Comment: Скажите, а эту функцию `loginByCookie` самим нужно вызывать в скрипте? Правильно я Вас понял?

Comment: Просто у меня  `$enableAutoLogin = true` но эта функция `loginByCookie` не вызывается .

Comment: Если у вас есть собственный компонент для управления аутентификацией пользователей, вместо стандартного `yii\web\User`, то можете реализовать свой метод авторизации по кукам `loginByCookie` и в нем вызывать `validateAuthKey`. Если нет, то вызывать самим `loginByCookie` нет необходимости

Comment: А когда он должен вызываться, я не могу понять , но прост оне вызывается.  Я использую стандартную чистую yii2 конфигурацию.  При вызове  `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` не вызывается.

Comment: `if ($this->enableAutoLogin) {
            if ($this->getIsGuest()) {
                $this->loginByCookie();
            } elseif ($this->autoRenewCookie) {
                $this->renewIdentityCookie();
            }
        }`

Comment: В гугл хроме не вызывается, когда включенна функция сохранения истории. Так что всё работает. Спасибо .

Answer (score 1):

Если сессий нет (уничтожены) и при логинировании пользователя мы указывали «remenberMe» (то есть второй параметр метода `Yii::$app->user->login()`, чтобы кука установилась), то Yii2 попытаеся авторизовать пользователя с помощью куки, вот здесь-то и вызывается этот загадочный метод `validateAuthKey()` ...
Естественно, попытка авторизации будет происходить только в том случае, если мы обращаемся к сущности пользователя, например так:

```
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    echo Html::a('Выйти', ['logout']);
}
```

Это можно проверить, удалив сессии из временной папки сервера (то есть оттуда, где они храняться) и как-нибудь обозначить вызов `validateAuthKey()`, например так:

```
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    echo '<script>alert("' . __METHOD__ . '");</script>';
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}
```

<s>Ну или помидитировать над исходными кодами Yii2.</s>

Источники:

- <s>[метод проб и ошибок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA)</s> документация;
- [How to login user from a database in Yii Framework 2](http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-user-from-a-database-in-yii-framework-2/)